# Error in Workflow Designer XAML File

Tags: xaml, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a XAML file I exported from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. When I open it in VS 2010 I get the following error:

> Workflow Designer encountered problems with your document
>
> Please check the document for invalid content, namespaces, references or reference loops.
>
> 'Set property '{clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow}ActivityReference.AssemblyQualifiedName' threw an exception.' Line number '59' and line position '42'.

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Here is the referenced line in the XAML file:

```
 <mxswa:ActivityReference AssemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Activities.EvaluateExpression, Microsoft.Crm.Workflow, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" DisplayName="EvaluateExpression">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.dll` assembly in the Workflow Toolbox.

Open the Toolbox window in Visual Studio (usually a fly-out from the left hand side), right click and select Add Items.  Add a reference to the above assembly which is available in the bin folder of the SDK and you should see the tooling pane light up with additional custom CRM activities.  You should now be able to load/compile your custom workflow

Comment: The project already has them loaded in the toolbox - I double-checked...and I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you also have a reference to Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.dll v5?

Comment: I have microsoft.crm.sdk.proxy.dll referenced and it is version 5.0.9690.2740 - from the latest SDK.